# Is there a way to sum up all the columns and rows in a 2d array without using np.sum()?

Tags: python, numpy

this is my current code:

```
M = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6]])

def np_sum_rows(M):  
  rows = []
  for i in range(len(M)):
    rows = M[i, 0:len(M[0])
  return rows.sum()
```

I want the function to return a vector [6 15]. However, the for loop can only store and return 15.
I am positively stumped by this problem and cannot think of any way else but using the for loop.

Comment: Why don't you want to use np.sum? That is the fastest and the recommended way to sum a numpy array. You can specify the `axis` argument to get to it sum across row or columns

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Like Pranav said, why not use `np.sum()`? If this is homework, please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). If you don't know where to even start, your teacher will probably be a better resource than us. BTW, if you want more/other tips, see [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `M.sum(axis=1)` gets what you want

Comment: Right, this is a homework assignment and they are using np.sum() to check our answers so...

Comment: So you want us to do your homework for you without even trying to do it yourself? No thanks!

Comment: brother, did you miss all the work I did above? I mean I will submit what I have now to for evaluation I'm just looking for ways to improve it

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/39188 "all the work you did above" still uses `np.sum`. you only get the sum of your last row because you set `rows` to a single row in the loop. Then you return its sum. You should calculate the sum of _each_ row inside the loop and append _that sum_ to a list that you'll eventually return

Comment: Mb, I should have clarified that we are not allowed to use .append either. So we are not allowed to use np.sum and list operations which is the reason why I am so confused.

Comment: When you say your homework forbids you from using `np.sum` and then show your own effort that in fact uses that function, you haven't shown your work _towards the task specified in your homework_. When you ask a homework question, we want you to try to solve it _with the specified constraints_, and then ask a question. Asking us to modify a code when that code breaks a fundamental constraint that's been imposed upon you is like asking us to write completely new code and do your work for you

Comment: Not allowed to use `np.sum` or list operations - I'd go with a list comprehension like Mike's answer below, but that is a strange set of constraints. I wonder what your teacher is trying to teach by imposing these. IMO "sum rows of a _'2d array'_ without `numpy` should have been an exercise performed on _lists of lists_. The whole point of numpy is it's relatively super-quick with array operations

Comment: I see where you are coming from now. In another words, if I am not allowed to use np.sum or append then this question is going to need some other stuff that is fundamentally different from these functions?

Answer (score 0):

You could apply `reduce` method that comes from functional programming background. It's possible in both Python and `numpy`-based ways.

In Python you need to apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of sequence.

```
import functools
M = M.tolist() #convert array to list in order to make iteration faster
[reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, m) for m in M]
>>> [6, 15]
```

In `numpy` you don't need to define a function usually. Universal functions (or `ufunc` for short) such as `add`, `multiply` etc. are used instead.

```
np.add.reduce(M, axis=1)
>>> array([ 6, 15])
```

Note that more common way is to apply `np.sum` on axis 1. So it's strongly adviced to get used to a concept of `numpy` axes.